# No suitable constructor for entity type 'LineString'

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, postgis

Trying to migrate integration tests from the in-memory database to the PostGIS one, I always catch that exception when I call `EnsureDeleted` or `EnsureCreated` methods:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
No suitable constructor found for entity type 'LineString'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'points' in 'LineString(Coordinate[] points)'; cannot bind 'points', 'factory' in 'LineString(CoordinateSequence points, GeometryFactory factory)'.
```

With in-memory tests, all is working fine.

The only model with spatial data is this:

```cs
public class SurveilledArea
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "geometry (polygon)")]
    public Polygon Polygon { get; set; }

    public string AvigilonAlertId { get; set; }

    public int MunicipalityId { get; set; }

    public virtual Municipality Municipality { get; set; }
}
```

and my DbContext is this

```cs
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> dbContextOptions) : base(dbContextOptions)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<SurveilledArea> Areas { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Municipality> Municipalities { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Report> Reports { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasPostgresExtension("postgis");

        modelBuilder.Entity<SurveilledArea>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Municipality)
            .WithMany(p => p.SurveilledAreas)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.MunicipalityId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Report>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Device)
            .WithMany(p => p.Reports)
            .HasForeignKey(p => new { p.DeviceType, p.DeviceAdId })
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Municipality>()
            .HasIndex(p => p.ShortCode)
            .IsUnique();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Device>()
            .HasKey(device => new {device.Type, device.AdvertisingId});

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, you are saying, you don't have any `LineString` class in your code?

Comment: So, I have done a solution-wide search and I do not have any LineString, I only have a Polygon and both inherit from Geometry (but I think it is not very relevant).

Comment: Have you added `o => o.UseNetTopologySuite()` in `Npgsql`'s configuration? You *do* have a LineString, provided you installed [Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NetTopologySuite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NetTopologySuite)

Comment: Please post the Npgsql and DbContext configuration from Startup.cs. Have you added `UseNetTopologySuite()` anywhere?

Comment: Yes. Cloning the repo, deleting the migration folder and recreating them have resolved the problem. Now, for this project I am the only developer on the backend and I know I can do that, but the problem is for a team project.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a class that contained a Polygon property

```
public NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Polygon Polygon { get; set; }
```

You may need to add a package ref to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite

Then in your data context builder implement something like this

```
   public static MyDataContext CreateContext(string sqlConnectionStr) {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDataContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(sqlConnectionStr, x => x.UseNetTopologySuite()
        return new MyDataContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
```